# Multiple Views in ViewGroup or single View with multiple drawn elements to efficiently create dial gauge?

Tags: android, android-view, viewgroup, gauge

I want to design a gauge View in Android, for example a round thermometer with a rotating needle.

For efficiency / speed, when new data arrives I'd like to re-draw only the parts of the View that change (e.g. the rotating needle).

My initial test class extended View, and I had to re-draw the entire view (moving and non-moving elements) in onDraw() each time new data arrived.

I found an example (http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/) that suggests drawing the non-moving components onto a Bitmap. This Bitmap is drawn in onDraw() using canvas.drawBitmap. In this way you only need to draw the individual non-moving graphic elements (regenerate the Bitmap) when something changes the non-moving parts of the View (e.g. resizing the View).

My idea for optimization was different. I think perhaps my gauge should extend ViewGroup rather than View. Then within the ViewGroup I could create individual Views for the non-moving and moving parts of the gauge. I would draw the non-moving View once, and never force it to invalidate(). Then I would draw the moving needle as a separate View (aligned in the ViewGroup such that it overlays the non-moving View) which I could invalidate() when new data arrives, so it would be re-drawn. Am I missing something that makes this a bad way to do it?

For example, is my assumption incorrect that the non-moving background View will not need to be re-drawn (i.e. have its onDraw called) as the overlaid rotating-needle View in the same ViewGroup is changed? Or does having the needle View change force the background View in the same ViewGroup to get re-drawn as well, due to the Views overlapping?

Many thanks.

Comment: Exactly working on same thing but stuck at ViewGroup. And currently I am trying to understand what is ViewGroup.

Comment: We ended up doing it similarly to that example link in my question.